# Can I apply a media query to a div to detect if it has a scroll bar or not?

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, scrollbar

I have a div with `overflow-y: auto` which means it will display a vertical scroll bar when the content takes up more height than the height of the div. This pushes the content over horizontally to make room for the scroll bar, which is fine, but then it becomes misaligned with the headers which are above the div.

No scroll bar:

[image]

Scroll bar:

[image]

Is there a way in CSS to detect when the scroll bar appears and add some padding/margin to the right of the headers in response?

I've looked up containment (here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-contain-3/) and attempted to do something like this:

```
                    .drivers-box {
                        padding: 5px;
                        border: 1px solid $ra-pam-control-border-grey;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 65px;
                        overflow-y: auto;
                        container-type: inline-size;
                    }

                    .driver-header {
                        padding: 0 6px;
                    }
                    
                    @container (min-width: 280px) {
                        .driver-header {
                            padding: 0 15px 0 6px;
                        }
                    }
```

```
<div class="drivers">
    <div class="driver-row driver-header">
        <div style="font-weight: 100">{{ 'CEBM_DRIVERS_LABEL' | translate }}</div>
        <div class="driver-row-btns">
            <i class="fas fa-chart-scatter" style="cursor: auto;" title="show in scatter plot"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-chart-line" style="cursor: auto;" title="show in time series"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-fill" style="color: red; cursor: auto" title="select series color"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-trash" style="cursor: auto;" title="delete driver"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="drivers-box">
        <div class="driver-row" ng-repeat="driver in drivers">
            <div>{{ driver.name }}</div>
            <div class="driver-row-btns">
                <input type="checkbox" title="show in scatter plot" ng-checked="driver.showInScatterPlot" ng-click="showInScatterPlotClicked(driver.id)" />
                <input type="checkbox" title="show in time series" ng-checked="driver.showInTimeSeries" ng-click="showInTimeSeriesClicked(driver.id)"/>
                <i ng-style="{ color: driver.color }" class="fas fa-circle" title="select series color" ng-click="seriesColorClicked(driver.id)"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-trash" title="delete driver" ng-click="deleteDriverClicked(driver.id)"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="mini-btn" style="margin-top: 5px;" ng-click="addDriverClicked()">{{ 'CEBM_ADD_DRIVER_BTN_TEXT' | translate }}</button>
</div>
```

...but it had no effect. In fact, it seems like it doesn't understand the keywords `container-type` or `@container` (it's a scss file).

[image]

Am I using containment correctly? Should I be using containment or is there another way to solve my problem?

Thanks?

Comment: Your content looks as though it is a table. Is there a reason for not using HTML table for it?

Comment: That is a possibility, but the only way I can see this solving my problem is if the table header is included in the containing div with the scroll bar. But then the header would scroll as well which is not what we want.

Comment: Have you looked into having a sticky header?

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers (and different CSS) may set the scroll bar to different widths so a method which relied on testing whether there was a scroll bar or not would be very uncertain.

As your data looks as though it is tabular, here's a simple example of an HTML table with the head set as sticky. The following rows will then scroll while the head remains fixed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="vieWport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Title</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      height: 5em;
      overflow: auto;
      width: 20em;
    }
    
    input:checked~.container {
      height: 20em;
    }
    
    table {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    thead {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      background: white;
    }
    
    th,
    td {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"><label for="toggle">Click to make the container height bigger/smaller</label>
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>A</th>
          <th>B</th>
          <th>C</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Haworth. I implemented it and it seems to work fine.